# Syntax error causes Class does not exist ReflectionException PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have been having strange "Class does not exists" exceptions being thrown in my Laravel 5.6 app. Say I have a class with a syntax error:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function hello()  int
    {
    } 
}
```

(Notice the missing `:` in the return type)

I am accessing this class via method injection one of my laravel controllers. Instead of getting a syntax error, I get a "Class does not exist" exception.

When I fix the syntax error, everything works as expected.

I am used to seeing this error when there is an autoload/namespace issue, but never for a syntax error in the file. It is super inconvenient because I get no line number in the error stack trace.

It seems some syntax errors make this happen, some do not.

Any ideas?

Comment: it seems that due to syntax issue class does not compile at all and hence you are trying to access this class you got class not found issue rather than syntax issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think also. But I have never seen this before, I always had a syntax error with a line number.

Comment: Can you share some minimal code example to reproduce this behavior?